# Regex to remove `.` from a sub-string enclosed in square brackets

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, replace

I have this regex in C#:

```
\[.+?\]
```

This regex extracts the sub-strings enclosed between square brackets. But before doing that I want to remove `.` inside these sub-strings. For example, the string

```
hello,[how are yo.u?]There are [300.2] billion stars in [Milkyw.?ay].
```

should become

```
hello,[how are you?]There are [3002] billion stars in [Milkyw?ay].
```

I am not good at forming regular expression so don't have any idea of how to modify my regex.

Live example here: https://regex101.com/r/pL5uA1/1

Comment: why `?` got removed?

Comment: @AvinashRaj oh sorry, I missed it. :)

Comment: Are you sure that you got the backslash right? You need to double-escape it when you are writing regex in another language.

Comment: @sqd: C# has raw string syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove all the dots present inside the square brackets.

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"\.(?=[^\[\]]*\])", "");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pL5uA1/2)

To remove dot or `?`.

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"[.?](?=[^\[\]]*\])", "");
```